# Entity framework 6 usetransaction databasefirst throws UnintentionalCodeFirstException

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, ef-database-first

I'm trying to execute the following :

```
  SqlConnection cnSql = new SqlConnection(cnstring);
        cnSql.Open();
        SqlTransaction Transactie = default(SqlTransaction);
        Transactie = cnSql.BeginTransaction();
        SqlCommand cmddelbonh = new SqlCommand();
        cmddelbonh.Connection = Transactie.Connection;
        cmddelbonh.Transaction = Transactie;
        cmddelbonh.CommandText = "update artikelgroepen set OMSN='XXXXX' where ID = 3";
        cmddelbonh.ExecuteNonQuery();


        using (CXNACC_TESTFIRMA cxn = new CXNACC_TESTFIRMA(cnSql))
        {
            cxn.Database.UseTransaction(Transactie);
            var myList = cxn.ARTIKELS.Take(100).ToList();
            cxn.ARTIKELS.First().OMSN = "XXXXX";
            cxn.SaveChanges();
        }

        Transactie.Commit();
```

This line 
    cxn.Database.UseTransaction(Transactie); 
enters the OnModelCreating on the Context and throws a UnintentionalCodeFirstException

When commenting out the throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException
it works but I don't like having to comment out an error which shouldn't be triggered anyway.

I googled around, but found no answers as to how use the UseTransaction feature of EF6 in a databasefirst context.

Before you ask : the connectionString for Entity is present in the app.config.

Any thoughts on this please?

Thanks

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this.

Comment: I found this [article](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/) which explains a bit more about database-first vs code-first... 

It seems that using the constructor taking the connection as parameter (your line: `using (CXNACC_TESTFIRMA cxn = new CXNACC_TESTFIRMA(cnSql))` ) will use code-first strategy to build the context 

I would also like to find a way to use the UseTransaction feature of EF6 with database-first, because so far I was unsuccessful, but I am afraid it would not be even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [article](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/) which explains a bit more about database-first vs code-first...

It seems that using the constructor taking the connection as parameter (your line: `using (CXNACC_TESTFIRMA cxn = new CXNACC_TESTFIRMA(cnSql))` ) will use code-first strategy to build the context

But then I was advised the following:

> For EF to use the metadata from your EDMX file you need to pass in an
>   EntityConnection rather than a straight up SqlConnection.
>
> If you want the SqlConnection to be able to use for other tasks
>   outside of the context then you can always create the EntityConnection
>   and then grab the StoreConnection off it:

```
  var entityConnection = new EntityConnection("name=AdventureWorksEntities");
  var dbConnection = entityConnection.StoreConnection;
```

> Because EntityConnection derives from DbConnection, you can still pass
>   it into the same constructor on DbContext that you were trying to use.